# Binding is not updating

Tags: swiftui

```
    var binding :  Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(get: {
            text
        }, set: {
            onTextChange($0)
        })
    }

  TextField( "", text: binding)
        .foregroundColor(isValid  ? YOUNG_NIGHT : VENETIAN_RED   )
```

it is not updating the TextField until another TextField is updated, some reason binding not trigger redraw

Comment: `var binding: ... ` is a computed property and does not update the view unless
 it triggers a state change. That is, in your `onTextChange($0)`
 you should have `text` changed, eg `text = $0`, then the view will be updated.
 Otherwise the view will not change. Assuming you have declared `@State var text = ""`

Comment: i am using viewmodel and need stateless view

Comment: so what is `text`? Can you show how you declare it in your View?

Comment: @Published var text: String

Comment: I presume this is in your viewmodel, if so then you should have `viewmodel.text` in your `binding`, and change that in your `onTextChange($0)`, as described in my first comment. Show how you declare your viewmodel in your view, and how you update it in your `onTextChange($0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code to show that you have to change the state (state model) for the view to update.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
    @Published var isValid: Bool = true
    // ...
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel() // <--- here, state object, or passed in

    var binding: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(get: {
            viewModel.text  // <--- here
        }, set: {
            onTextChange($0)
        })
    }
    
    func onTextChange(_ txt: String) {
        // ... some code logic here
        viewModel.text = txt // <--- here, must change the state to trigger view update
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: binding).border(.red)
        Text(viewModel.text)  // <-- for testing
    }
    
        // alternative
   //    var body: some View {
   //        TextField("", text: $viewModel.text)
   //            .border(viewModel.isValid ? .green : .red)
   //            .foregroundColor(viewModel.isValid ? .green : .red)
   //            .onChange(of: viewModel.text) {
   //                // ... onTextChange code logic here
   //                // for example
   //                viewModel.isValid = !viewModel.text.contains{$0.isNumber}
   //            }
   //    }
   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood correctly, but it seems like you want the color of the text in the textfield to change in real-time based on the validation conditions. In that case, you can try the following approach. I don't know your entire code, so I've named the validation function `validateText()` arbitrarily.

Sample validation function:

```
   func validateText(_ text: String) -> Bool {
        // This is just sample
        return text.count > 3
    }
```

Add `.onChange` method to TextField:

```
TextField("", text: binding)
    .onChange(of: text, { oldValue, newValue in
     isValid = validateText(newValue)
     })
    .foregroundColor(isValid  ? YOUNG_NIGHT : VENETIAN_RED   )
```